# symfony reload page after deleting item

Tags: symfony

I have some item on my page and delete button in front of each item,
I want to delete and reload the same page.
So far, I go to another page, I want to avoid that:

I don't want go to "skilllearndelete/{id}" page, I want just reload after deleting

here is my controller :

```
public function deleteAction($id)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('EotoUserBundle:UserLearnskill')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find UserLearnskill entity.');
        }
        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
        return  $this->render("EotoUserBundle:Learnskill:delete.html.twig",array('id' => $id));

    }
```

Here is my route:

```
userlearnskill_delete:
    path:     skilllearndelete/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: EotoUserBundle:UserLearnskill:Delete }
```

here is my page where I display the items :

```
                <td><a href="{{ path('userlearnskill_delete', { 'id': skill.id }) }} " onclick="return confirm('Do you want delete {{ skill.learnskill}} skill ?')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove-item"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically accomplished by returning a redirect to the previous page after your delete operation. For the most part, the user will just see the page reload unless there is an uncaught exception.

In your delete action:

`return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('routename_to_my_original_page'));`